# C++ - Noob - Simple Try/Catch

Tags: c++, exception

I am trying to write a simple try/catch statement, but I keep on getting compiler errors. This is my code:

```
int divide(int x, int y)
{
    if (y == 0) {
        throw 0;
    }
    return x / y;
}

Exception::Exception()
{
    try {
        cout << divide(10, 0) << "\n"; 
    } catch (int e) {
        cout << "Cannot divide by " << e << "\n";
    } 
}
```

I am getting the following compiler errors:

LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int_*thiscall Exception::divide(int,int" (?divide@Exception@@QAEHH@Z) referenced in function "public:*_thiscall Exception::Exception(void)"(??0Exception@@QAE@XZ)

LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: It would be helpful to show the error message you are receiving.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the error message. I just added it!

Comment: change `Exception::Exception()` to `int main()`

Comment: When your fingers type "I get an error", the very next thing they should type is the **exact** error you're getting, including any error messages, exception addresses, or other info you receive. It makes it much more likely your question won't be closed, and will also get you help much faster. You need to remember that we can't see your screen (or read your mind) from where we're sitting, so we have the information you provide and nothing else to go on. Please edit your code to indicate what error you're getting and where in the code you're getting it. Thanks. :)

Comment: Yup. I just forgot to include the errors. I included it on the bottom of my post :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My magic remote debugging skills tell me that `divide` is a member of `Exception`, but you're defining it in the global namespace. Prefix `divide` with `Exception::`, a la

```
int Exception::divide(int x, int y)
{
    if (y == 0) {
        throw 0;
    }
    return x / y;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are getting is a linker error. You mentioned `divide` as a member function of the `Exception` class but forgot to do it's implementation. Just qualify the call with `::`.

```
 cout << ::divide(10, 0) << "\n";  // Take the function at global scope
                                   // This still leaves the member function implemenation
                                   // unimplemented which is bad though.
```

or

```
int Exception :: divide(int x, int y) { .... }
```

Comment: The former is more of a bandaid solution, but +1 for giving all the options (and the comment you added makes it better)